# C - Code after 'if' (and inside a 'while') does not execute

Tags: c, if-statement, while-loop, linked-list

A bit of background for this question, I have a linked list with names, in which I wan't to find a user input name. For convenience purposes, I copy the name (if found) to the same buffer, like so:

```
  aux = filtCountriesHead;  //head of my list
  while (aux != NULL){
    if (strstr(aux->data.name, buffer) != NULL){
      strcpy(buffer, aux->data.name);
      foundName = 1;
      break;
    } 
      aux = aux->next;  //this is skipped for some reason
  }
```

When I run this, it enters an infinite loop, because it does not execute the aux = aux->next line, which I found by running in the debugger. It doesn't execute anything in the 'if' (and even if it did, the 'break;' would make it exit the cycle, not run it again) so I'm all out of ideas. Anyone have an explanation?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is going to be extremely hard for us to help you with unless you create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to show us. Maybe the assignment is made but you have something wrong with your links? When you step through the debugger, what is the value of `aux`? What is the value of `aux->next`?

Comment: Have you printed out your list to make sure it is correct?  Your code here looks ok, so with the behavior you are describing, there must be a loop or something in your list.

Comment: You probably have a node pointing to itself. Try printing out `aux` and `aux->next` (i.e. the memory addresses) on every iteration, at some point they'll probably be the same. You instead want to see `aux->next` be 0 (`NULL`) at some point

Comment: You should watch `aux` while debugging, does it look valid i.e. point at an object with reasonable looking values and a reasonable looking vfpt? Or does it stay the same? Either way `aux->next` probably hasn't been set to a value you expect.

Comment: How do you know that `aux = aux->next;` is being skipped? Did you set a breakpoint on that line?

Comment: @pkpnd While a decent MCVE would reduce the required level of guessing, your comment is so convincing that I propose to hazard the bet and make it an answer. I cannot see anyting described by OP which is not explained by it.

Comment: I am sure the list is correctly linked and functioning, all the other functions of my program work fine and I am familiar with linked lists. I know for a fact the line is being skipped, as it does not show up in the debugger at all, it simply cycles through the while, the if, and the end bracket of the while, repeating

Comment: Are your strings `NULL`-terminated?

Comment: If a line of your code is not visible at all in the debugger, how can you be sure that the executable being debugged is the result of building the code containing the line? Can you apply some other change, which is easily visible in the running executable (and maybe its output) and thereby prove that the code we look at is what is being debugged

Comment: @AlexandreRodrigues Please follow my suggestion of printing `aux` and `aux->next` before the update, on every iteration, and report your findings. It'll take at most 1 minute to implement.

Comment: "I know for a fact" *famous last words*.

Comment: Just because `buffer` is shown to be a substring of `aux->data.name`, does not mean that `buffer` is large enough to copy `aux->data.name` to.

Answer (score 1):

Without more data, such as observations about `aux`'s values, there is no way to be sure about the core issue. But here's a likely explanation...

---

If you observe an infinite loop where `aux = aux->next;` appears to do nothing, that must mean `aux->next` equals `aux`, i.e., `aux` points to itself. Typically the tail of a linked list points to `NULL` instead.

Of course, the cyclic list structure would need to be fixed elsewhere, since the list isn't being created in the provided code.